# Should Java SE Binary be allowed to communicate with my private/public networks?

Tags: java, firewall

I downloaded the Elder Scrolls Online Tamriel Unlimited game on my pc and got a popup explaining that Java SE Binary wants to communicate with public and private networks. I am a noob. I don't know what to select. What is Java trying to do here???

Comment: Most likely, "Java SE Binary" isn't trying to communicate. Rather, some application *written* in Java (note: Java is not the same thing as Javascript that your web browser runs) is trying to communicate. We might be able to help you better if you [edit] your question and state exactly what you did just before the popup appeared.

Answer (score 2):

It's asking for permission to communicate through your firewall.

Windows has different firewall policies for public and private networks (public ones should be more strict for safety reasons), so basically it wants to know if you want to allow Java to communicate with the *outside world*, depending on each network type.

In my opinion, if you don't know much about this, I'd recommend you to allow Java to communicate in both public and private ones, since it may save you trouble in the future.